# Laravel 5.5 API resources for collections (standalone data)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5, thephpleague-fractal

I was wondering if it is possible to define different data for item resource and collection resource.

For collection I only want to send `['id', 'title', 'slug']` but the item resource will contain extra details `['id', 'title', 'slug', 'user', etc.]`

**I want to achieve something like:**

```
class PageResource extends Resource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'slug' => $this->slug,
            'user' => [
                'id' => $this->user->id,
                'name' => $this->user->name,
                'email' => $this->user->email,
            ],
        ];
    }
}

class PageResourceCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'slug' => $this->slug,
        ];
    }
}
```

**PageResourceCollection** will not work as expected because it uses **PageResource** so it needs

```
return [
            'data' => $this->collection,
       ];
```

I could duplicate the resource into `PageFullResource` / `PageListResource` and `PageFullResourceCollection` / `PageListResourceCollection` but I am trying to find a better way to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The Resource class has a collection method on it. You can return that as the parameter input to your ResourceCollection, and then specify your transformations on the collection.

Controller:

```
class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return new PageResourceCollection(PageResource::collection(Page::all()));
    }

    public function show(Page $page)
    {
        return new PageResource($page);
    }
}
```

Resources:

```
class PageResource extends Resource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'slug' => $this->slug,
            'user' => [
                'id' => $this->user->id,
                'name' => $this->user->name,
                'email' => $this->user->email,
            ],
        ];
    }
}

class PageResourceCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'data' => $this->collection->transform(function($page){
                return [
                    'id' => $page->id,
                    'title' => $page->title,
                    'slug' => $page->slug,
                ];
            }),
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be nice if Laravel could create a `PageResource` for each item in the  collection by itself.

Comment: @DeesOomens actually it does: just do `return PageResource::collection($collection);`

Comment: You can also use your Resource object inside the transform method:

`return [
    'data' => $this->collection->transform(function($page){
        return PageResource::make($page);
    })
];`

Comment: Anyone trying to do this in Laravel 6 might hit this 'bug' https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/32513 - The solution would be something like: `'data' => $this->collectResource($this->collection)->transform(static function ($page) { ...`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want the response fields to have the same value in the Resource and Collection, you can reuse the Resource inside the Collection

PersonResource.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

class PersonResource extends Resource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
//        return parent::toArray($request);

        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'person_type' => $this->person_type,
            'first_name' => $this->first_name,
            'last_name' => $this->last_name,
            'created_at' => (string) $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => (string) $this->updated_at,
        ];
    }
}
```

PersonCollection.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class PersonCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\AnonymousResourceCollection
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
//        return parent::toArray($request);
        return PersonResource::collection($this->collection);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the cleaner and more elegant way of writing resource and collection. This also helps maintain the resource and collection easier in the long run

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer works, if you are not interested in using links and meta data. If you want, simply return:

```
return new PageResourceCollection(Page::paginate(10));
```

in your controller. You should also look to eager load other dependent relationships before passing over to the resource collection.