# Resource in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

**ProductController**
[image: This is ProductController]

**API routes**
[image: This is ProductCollection]

**Error**
[image: And here is my route API]

I get error:

> ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
>   Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$name" when i run Laravel app in browser with link :http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products!

Help me to solved this bug thank you so much (I'm a newbie to learn Laravel, thanks!!!)]

Comment: share your code.

Comment: Hi, you can paste your code snippets by text. Images are extra.
Also you can format code with 3 symbols " ` " at the beginning of the code and 3 " ` " at the end.

Comment: [Please do not post images as text or encourage people to post images as text.](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: my Controller with function index : public function index()
    {
        return  ProductCollection::collection(Product::all());
    }

Comment: and code in ProductCollection : public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->name,
            'totalPrice' => round( (1- ($this->discount/100))*$this->price,2),
            'rating' => $this->reviews->count()> 0 ?round($this ->reviews->sum('star')/$this->reviews->count(),2) :'No rating yet',
            'href' => [
                'link' => route('products.show',$this->id)
            ]
        ];
    }

Comment: Tks, i try to use stack overflow and my English is low.

Comment: Please can you add the code for you `ProductCollection` to  your question i.e. edit the question and copy and paste the code into it. (please do not add it as a comment or add an image).

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing your data in the wrong way, like `$this->name` in your ProductCollection.

As stated [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources#resource-collections) in the Laravel Documentation,
you have to access your properties via the `$this->collection` property which is populated with the mapping of each item of the collection.

Try using:

`$this->collection->name` and you should be fine.

Comment: Tks but my errors still appear the same.Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$name

Comment: Is there any other way to use resources instead of collections in laravel?when to use resources and when to use collections in laravel? Tks!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Andrea Campana. I have found some suggestions from Laravel's homepage!Then I tried with : $this->collection->get() and everything looks good; but i still search andI will try to find a way to use it correctly.If you have a great standard and explanation about this, please share with me, thank you very much

Comment: i find a post here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46388205/laravel-5-5-api-resources-for-collections-standalone-data.