# Reading data from in vue/cli from Laravel ResourceCollection

Tags: laravel, laravel-resource

In Laravel 6 backend rest api app I use ResourceCollection and Resourcem defintion like :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;
use App\Facades\MyFuncsClass;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class TaskCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    public function toArray($task)
    {

        return [
            $this->collection->transform(function($task){
                return [
                    'id' => $task->id,
                    'name' => $task->name,
                    'slug' => $task->slug,
                    ...
                    'events' => !empty($task->events) ? $task->events : [],
                    'events_count' => !empty($task->events_count) ? $task->events_count : 0,
                    'created_at' => $task->created_at,
                    'updated_at' => $task->updated_at,
                ];
            }),
        ];

    }

    public function with($task)
    {
        return [
            'meta' => [
                'version'=>MyFuncsClass::getAppVersion()
            ]
        ];
    }

}
```

I found this decision at
[Laravel 5.5 API resources for collections (standalone data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46388205/laravel-5-5-api-resources-for-collections-standalone-data)

and it works for me, but I dislike the way I got data on client part, so for listing of data defined in control :

```
return (new TaskCollection($tasks));
```

I have to write in vue/cli app :

```
axios.post(this.apiUrl + '/adminarea/tasks-filter', filters, this.credentialsConfig)
    .then((response) => {
        this.tasks = response.data.data[0]
        this.tasks_total_count = response.data.meta.total
        this.tasks_per_page = response.data.meta.per_page
```

and when I need to get 1 item I define in laravel's control :

```
return (new TaskCollection([$task])); // I have to wrap it as array
```

and I have to write in vue/cli app :

```
axios.get(this.apiUrl + '/adminarea/tasks/' + this.task_id, this.credentialsConfig)
    .then((response) => {
        // console.log('response::')
        // console.log(response)
        //
        this.taskRow = response.data.data[0][0]
```

I dislike syntax like data.data[0] and data.data[0][0] and even that works for me

In my app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php I have lines :

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Auth;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {

        Resource::withoutWrapping(); // looks like that does not work for ResourceCollection!

<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Auth;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Resource::withoutWrapping();
        ...
```

If there is a way to get rid of data.data[0] and data.data[0][0] in vue/cli part ?

**MODIFIED 2:**
I created new resource with few columns as app/Http/Resources/Skill.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class Skill extends JsonResource
{
    public static $wrap = 'skills';
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $request->id,
            'name' => $request->name,
            'user_id' => $request->user_id,
            'user_name' => $request->user_name,
            'skill_id' => $request->skill_id,
            'skill_name' => $request->skill_name,
            'rating' => $request->rating,
            'created_at' => $request->created_at,
        ];
    }
}
```

and app/Http/Resources/SkillCollection.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use App\Facades\MyFuncsClass;
use App\Http\Resources\Skill;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class SkillCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    public static $wrap = 'skills';
    public function toArray($request)
    {

        return $this->collection->transform(function($request){
            parent::toArray($request);
            });
    }
```

and resulting I have empty "skills":[null,null,null,null] results. What is wrong ?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason why you define a `ResourceCollection` and not using a class for returning singular resources, e.g. defining `TaskResource` that extends `JsonResource` and then returning `TaskResource::collection($tasks)`?

Comment: I think your resource is being wrapped in `data` regardless of your using `withoutWrapping()` because your `meta` function returns a non-empty object. Check out the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/11f410a3439f47efb60f19cf100e719e461fd75b/src/Illuminate/Http/Resources/Json/ResourceResponse.php#L67) here where Laravel wraps your response if you have `with` data.

Comment: I tried JsonResource at first, but as I need method
public function with($task)
    ...
as in my code, I tried it and it did not work for me.
I found that this “with” method is not accessible with JsonResource, but only for ResourceCollection.
Is it so ?

Comment: I tried several variants with wrapping, but failed. And sure I need to have 1 Collection item both for listing of elements and 1 element

Comment: How do you expect your response to look if you want it to return `with` data? Laravel wraps your response in a `data` array if you have `with` data because otherwise it will be mixed up with your `with` data. For example, it will try to return an array like `[$task1, $task2, 'meta' => ['version' => 1]]]`.

Comment: I search how to reduce data.data[0] and data.data[0][0] if that is possible. Keeping the functionality. Also very interesting who used ResourceCollection which syntax they use both on server/vlient...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The first thing you can do is to use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the [response data](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema) from your Axios request:

```
axios.get(this.apiUrl + '/adminarea/tasks/' + this.task_id, this.credentialsConfig)
    .then(({ data }) => {
        this.taskRow = data.data[0][0]
```

So now `response.data.data[0][0]` is shortened to `data.data[0][0]`.

2. The second thing you can do is, in the `toArray` function of your `TaskCollection` class, to return the transformed collection directly instead of wrapping it in an array:

```
    public function toArray($task)
    {
            return $this->collection->transform(function($task){
                return [
                    'id' => $task->i
                    ...
                ];
            });
    }
```

Now you don't need to use `[0]` everywhere. So instead of `data.data[0][0]`, you can access a single task with `data.data[0]`.

3. To avoid having to use `[0]` for singular responses, you should return a `JsonResource` instead of a `ResourceCollection`. For this you would need to move your code from inside `$this->collection->transform` to a new `JsonResource` class. For example:

`app/Http/Resources/TaskResource.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use App\Facades\MyFuncsClass;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class TaskResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($task)
    {
         return [
                    'id' => $this->id,
                    'name' => $this->name,
                    'slug' => $this->slug,
                    ...
                ];
    }

    public function with($task)
    {
        return [
            'meta' => [
                'version'=>MyFuncsClass::getAppVersion()
            ]
        ];
    }

}
```

Then you can return a single resource with

```
return new TaskResource($task);
```

In Javascript you will be able to get a single task with `data.data` now:

```
axios.get(this.apiUrl + '/adminarea/tasks/' + this.task_id, this.credentialsConfig)
    .then(({ data }) => {
        this.taskRow = data.data;
```

You can refactor your `TaskCollection` class to implicitly use your new `TaskResource` class for each task:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;
use App\Facades\MyFuncsClass;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class TaskCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }

    public function with($task)
    {
        return [
            'meta' => [
                'version'=>MyFuncsClass::getAppVersion()
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

4. Like I tried to explain in the comments, you won't be able to get away from having to wrap your results in a key (like `'data'`) while returning non-null values from the `with` function. If you don't believe me, temporarily remove your `with` function and you'll see that you'll be able to access your tasks simply with `data` (if you have disabled wrapping with `Resource::withoutWrapping();`).

However, one thing you can do is to customise the "wrap" key. For example, for a collection of tasks you might want it to be `tasks` and for a single task, just `task`. You can simply add a `$wrap` property to your `TaskCollection` and `TaskResource` classes:

```
class TaskCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    public static $wrap = 'tasks';
    ...
```

```
class TaskResource extends JsonResource
{
    public static $wrap = 'task';
```

Now you will be able to access a list of tasks from Javascript with `data.tasks` and a singular task with `data.task`:

```
axios.post(this.apiUrl + '/adminarea/tasks-filter', filters, this.credentialsConfig)
    .then(({ data }) => {
        this.tasks = data.tasks;
```

```
axios.get(this.apiUrl + '/adminarea/tasks/' + this.task_id, this.credentialsConfig)
    .then(({ data }) => {
        this.taskRow = data.task;
```

Comment: Great, thanks! The only thing I would like to ask is it possible to avoid using of 2 files : based on ResourceCollection and JsonResource ? Or  maybe 1 of them as wrapper of the second? I mean listing of fields could be rather long

Comment: Yes, if you return `return parent::toArray($request);` from `TaskCollection` it will automatically use the `toArray` function of `TaskResource` for each task. So you won't have to list the fields in both of those classes.

Comment: Pls look at MODIFIED 2:

Comment: The items in `Skill` should be `'id' => $this->id,` and not `'id' => $request->id,`